# Having trouble getting site to site VPN work using ASA 5505

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa, vpn, tunnel

I'm getting this on my ASA, and im' not sure why the remote tunnel won't work.

```
7|Jun 07 2015|20:03:19|713236|||||IP = remoteIP, IKE_DECODE SENDING Message (msgid=5b87b9d6) with payloads : HDR + HASH (8) + NOTIFY (11) + NONE (0) total length : 80
7|Jun 07 2015|20:03:19|715046|||||Group = remoteip, IP = remoteip, constructing qm hash payload
7|Jun 07 2015|20:03:19|715046|||||Group = remoteip, IP = remoteip, constructing blank hash payload
7|Jun 07 2015|20:03:19|715036|||||Group = remoteip, IP = remoteip, Sending keep-alive of type DPD R-U-THERE-ACK (seq number 0x7056e351)
7|Jun 07 2015|20:03:19|715075|||||Group = remoteip, IP = remoteip, Received keep-alive of type DPD R-U-THERE (seq number 0x7056e351)
7|Jun 07 2015|20:03:19|715047|||||Group = remoteip, IP = remoteip, processing notify payload
7|Jun 07 2015|20:03:19|715047|||||Group = remoteip, IP = remoteip, processing hash payload
7|Jun 07 2015|20:03:19|713236|||||IP = remoteip, IKE_DECODE RECEIVED Message (msgid=696d6f13) with payloads : HDR + HASH (8) + NOTIFY (11) + NONE (0) total length : 80
7|Jun 07 2015|20:03:19|713906|||||IKE Receiver: Packet received on localip:500 from remoteip:500
```

I'm getting phase 1 and phase 2 completion on the other ASA 5505.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing is fully expected of an operational Site-Site VPN.  The key lies here:

```
Group = remoteip, IP = remoteip, Sending keep-alive of type DPD R-U-THERE-ACK (seq number 0x7056e351)
Group = remoteip, IP = remoteip, Received keep-alive of type DPD R-U-THERE (seq number 0x7056e351)
```

These messages are a part of what is known as **Dead Peer Detection**, or **DPD**.  DPD sends periodic keep alive messages (known as "*R-U-THERE*" messages) to the opposing peer.  Upon reception of such a message, the other peer will respond with a keep alive acknowledgement (known as "*R-U-THERE-ACK*").  This informs the original peer that full, two way connectivity between the peers is working just fine.  The operation of DPD is described in more detail in [RFC 3706](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3706).

For what its worth, your log messages are backwards.  The bottom message is the oldest, and the top message is the newest.

That said, DPD on the ASA is sent only when no active traffic is detected.  Because if traffic is detecting *going both directions*, that intrinsically confirms the tunnel is up, so no additional verification is necessary.  The ASA only starts sending DPD keep alives, if no traffic has been seen recently.

So in the end, you've shown us the debug of a fully working tunnel.  Nothing in what you posted indicated a problem.  So if a Problem does exist, you'll have to provide much more debugs and context, maybe even sample configurations.  I would also suggest the output of `show ipsec sa` and show `vpn-sessiondb`.

Comment: Also, Its weird, because the other side says its fine and is reporting normal syslog...

Comment: To be clear.  This forum is more of a Q&A than a specific "help me figure this out back and forth".  If you're going to post new evidence, or describe a new problem, I would suggest using a new question.  Your initial question is about DPD messages, and I spoke to that in my answer.  If you add more context and change the intent of the original question, my answer will be made irrelevent.  If you're really interested in a 'back and forth' conversation, your best bet is the [Network Engineering Chat Room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11177/general-network-engineering-recommendations)